# TensorFlow computation results slightly vary

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Since this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429313/why-do-tensorflow-tf-learn-classification-results-vary-a-lot) only describes the variety of predictions based on learning approaches, I want to find out of curiosity why TensorFlow computations **slightly vary**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session() # TensorFlow session

var1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # one placeholder
var2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # another one
addition_node = var1 + var2 # Variable Addition Node

array = sess.run(addition_node, {var1: [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], var2:[1,1,1]}) # Array with values
print(array)
```

Expected ouput:

```
[ 2.1000000   3.20000000  4.30000000]
```

Actual output:

```
[ 2.0999999   3.20000005  4.30000019]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal for 32-bit floating point values.  Those 1.1, 2,2 and 3.3 values are not exactly represented in 32-bit floating point.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3], dtype=np.float32)
y = np.array([1, 1, 1], dtype=np.float32)
x+y

>>> array([ 2.0999999 ,  3.20000005,  4.30000019], dtype=float32)
```

If you haven't read it, you might want to google "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" to understand better the limitations.

Comment: This! Specifically for python you can find more here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html